# Is it possible to use Power BI desktop data source from another gateway not from your local computer?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power BI desktop to create reports.
I want to use data source from another "On-premises data gateway".
In the Power Query Editor, I am changing the source to something like "= Sql.Database("SVR-SSH01\SQL2019", "WSP-GSK")".

I already created a connection in my Power BI service, it says it's online so everything seems to be just fine except that my Power BI Desktop is not connecting to another gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI Desktop cannot use the connections you configure in the service or connect through a Gateway.  You can create a new idea for that here: https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/ideas/

Either connect directly from your desktop to the data source, or you can design reports online or in Power BI Desktop after deploying your Dataset to the Power BI Service.