# Can't connect PowerBI to SQL Server through OnPrem data connector

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I'm new to this setup, but I think I've all the steps complete. However when I attempt to connect to a SQL server from PowerBI Desktop it keeps failing.

Things checked so far:

PBI Service (in 365):

- under my admin account and user account, shows both OnPrem connected and online
- under my admin account and user account, shows connection to db both connected and online

OnPrem Data Connector:

- Shows all green for available connections,
- Diag test shows all tests successful,

Infrastructure:

- AzureAD joined Azure Virtual Server Microsoft Windows Server 2022
- OnPrem data connector on the AzureVM
- SQL Server 2019, with local admin windows user
- Local laptop not connected to server via network (as I want to use the data connector only)
- PowerBI Desktop on the Laptop, signed in with user account (not my admin one)

Tests:

- have installed PowerBI desktop on server and connected with the same credentials I'm trying via the laptop, and I can connect and pull data successfully.
- have tried with the admin credentials on local laptop and makes no difference.
- have made sure hostnames/names/spelling/caps are all the same across the setup/logins

Method:

- From desktop PBI I'm just 'GetData' form SQL Server, and entering the normal server hostname and db. I'm new to this so it's my understanding that as I'm logged in with my user 365 account, that an admin account has assigned 'share' permissions on both the OnPrem connector & Connection setup in the 365 PBI Service, that it should allow me to pull data. Apologies if I've got that wrong :-(

Error:

Details: "Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: "OnPrem data connector" is that Power BI Gateway? Is your SQL Server in the cloud?

Comment: Hi Sam, 
Yes, the PowerBI Gateway (standard) as my on prem data connector.
It's a normal Azure VM, with SQL 2019 installed on it. (not Azure SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer: [Is it possible to use Power BI desktop data source from another gateway not from your local computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77025971/is-it-possible-to-use-power-bi-desktop-data-source-from-another-gateway-not-from)

In short - Power BI Gateway is for Power BI Service to connect to an onPrem datasource. You cannot use Power BI Desktop to connect via the gateway.

In your case, look to create a firewall rule to allow your local machine to connect to SQL Server AzVM. Then once you publish the report to PBI Service, the gateway will be used.

Comment: Thank you. So what's the point of the connector do you know, if I've to create a full network connection to the SQL VM anyway?

From that answer:
... or you can design reports online or in Power BI Desktop after deploying your Dataset to the Power BI Service...

After deploying your dataset to the powerbi service, is this not what I've done above or have I missed this step?
Thanks

Comment: The gateway is required so that once the report is published, the Power BI Service can connect to the onPrem datasource for data refresh. You can design and build your data model (dataset) first, publish that to the service and set-up refresh, then you can author your report on the published dataset on your local PC without the need of connecting to your data source, as your data source will now be the published dataset.